# CORS error when fetching and loading user images: "Access to image from origin has been blocked by CORS policy"

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, express, server, cors

I'm trying to fetch and load user images in my application.

but I keep encountering a CORS error. Here's the specific error message I'm receiving:

```
'home:1 Access to image at 'http://localhost:3001/assets/Screenshot%202023-06-19%20at%209.24.51%20AM.png' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.'
```

Here is my index.js within my server file.

```
 import express from "express";
import bodyParser from "body-parser";
import mongoose from "mongoose";
// const cors = require('cors');
import cors from 'cors';
import dotenv from "dotenv";
import multer from "multer";
import helmet from "helmet";
import morgan from "morgan";
import path from "path";
import { fileURLToPath } from "url";
import authRoutes from "./routes/auth.js";
import userRoutes from './routes/users.js'
import postRoutes from "./routes/posts.js";
import { register } from "./controllers/auth.js";
import { createPost } from "./controllers/posts.js";
import { verifyToken } from "./middleware/auth.js";
import User from "./models/User.js";
import Post from "./models/Post.js";


// CORS OPTIONS
const corsOptions = {
  origin: ['http://localhost:3000'],
  methods: ['GET', 'POST', 'PUT', 'PATCH'],
  allowedHeaders: ['Content-Type', 'Authorization','Access-Control-Allow-Origin' ],
};

/* CONFIGURATIONS */

const __filename = fileURLToPath(import.meta.url);
const __dirname = path.dirname(__filename);
dotenv.config();
const app = express();
app.use(express.json());
app.use(helmet());
// app.use(helmet.crossOriginResourcePolicy({ policy: "cross-origin" }));
// app.use(helmet());
app.use(morgan("common"));
app.use(bodyParser.json({ limit: "30mb", extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ limit: "30mb", extended: true }));
app.use("/assets", express.static(path.join(__dirname, "public/assets")));
// ! ENABLE LATER BEFORE DEPLOY
app.use(cors(corsOptions));
/* FILE STORAGE */
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, "public/assets");
  },
  filename: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, file.originalname);
  },
});
const upload = multer({ storage });

// Might have to create another post function for image upload on profile update

app.post("/auth/register", upload.single("picture"), register);
app.post("/posts", verifyToken, upload.single("picture"), createPost);


// ROUTES
app.use("/auth", authRoutes);
app.use("/users", userRoutes);
app.use("/posts", postRoutes);


/* MONGOOSE SETUP */
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 6001;
mongoose
  .connect(process.env.MONGO_URL, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
  })
  .then(() => {
    app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Server Port: ${PORT}`));
  })
  .catch((error) => console.log(`${error} did not connect`));
```

Despite setting up CORS correctly, I'm still experiencing this error. What could be the cause of this issue, and how can I resolve it?

I first got this error when i deployed the app. I deployed the frontend to vercel and the backend to heroku. So i decided to just switch back all of the request URLs. That didn't seem to fix the issue so i tried rolling back to a previous commit and now I'm still getting the same error. I never changed anything server side before deploying it to heroku so I'm not sure why all of a sudden it wants to bug out like this.

Comment: Do you have the origin set to localhost when deploying as well?